# PHP cURL request is not giving any output

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do this command line curl command through PHP cURL, I'm getting the output perfectly in commandline but not the same when I try with PHP.

```
curl -d "text=terrible" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

Tried to write a PHP cURL but I didn't get any output.

```
    $data = "text=terrible";
    $ch = curl_init('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);



  echo "<pre>";
   print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their API states they require the post to be form encoded data here [sentiment api](http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html).

### Excerpt

> To analyze the sentiment of some text, do an HTTP POST to http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/ with form encoded data containg the text you want to analyze. You’ll get back a JSON object response with 2 attributes:

To do this in PHP with curl, you must pass the header for `Content-Type` with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

### Demonstration

```
$data = "text=terrible";
$ch = curl_init('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Its good to use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` in cUrl calls for better monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

I think curl is not enable on your end. I tried your code and it is running properly.

Try to enable curl then try it.

1. Open your php.ini, situated in apache\bin.
2. Uncomment `;extension=php_curl.dll`.
3. Restart Apache.

Hope this will help

Comment: He would have got a PHP error if this was the case.

Comment: As @techie_28 mentioned and I stated in the question, I didn't get any output. No error either.